# MySQL defining DB columns

Tags: mysql, sql

i have questions abou creating tables.

Lets say i would like to create table xxx with column sss. what does it mean `NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` ?

another column has `DEFAULT NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
  `sss` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`mmm` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

when shall i use `Engine`?

thanks

Comment: read the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: This sounds like multiple questions.  [`DEFAULT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) and [`ENGINE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOT NULL means the column must have a value.

DEFAULT '0' means the default value of the column will be '0' unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT NULL` syntax on a column definition is a *constraint* which disallows a NULL value from being stored in the column. An attempt to insert a NULL value will raise an error.

The `DEFAULT` clause specifies a value that will be stored in the column when an insert does not provide a value for the column. When omitted from the column specification, the default is NULL.

In the case of the table definition in the question, a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO xxx (mmm) VALUES ('2013-08-22');
```

Will insert a row with a value of 0 assigned to the sss column, equivalent to this statement:

```
INSERT INTO xxx (sss, mmm) VALUES (0, '2013-08-22');
```

Similarly, if no value is supplied for mmm, it will be set to NULL.